# .net maui animations stuttering when called with animation.Commit

Tags: android, .net, animation, maui

I'm trying to create an expanding label that animates with an increasing height and with the increased height, everything below it is also automatically repositioned downward because it is within a VerticalStackLayout. I have created a `new Animation` in code with the following, and it works, however the animation is not smooth and stutters.

```
public void LabelHeightAnimTest(Label label, double newHeight, uint length)
{
var animation = new Animation(d => label.HeightRequest = d, label.Height, newHeight, Easing.SinInOut);
animation.Commit(label, "HeightAnimation", length: length, finished: (d, b) => { });
}
```

Does anyone know how I can animate the height of items like Labels without it stuttering? Does Hardware Acceleration need to be enabled on android? I've tested this on my phone and emulator, both have stuttering. Tested in Release mode and it still stutters.

I've tried creating animations in code and committing them using Animation.Commit with Microsoft.Maui.Controls

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a lot of different animation, and even 3D, and I have no stuttering. Check to see that there is not too much going on in the main thread. Also try out different easing. Always use acceleration.

This is how I do a button resizing, which is similar to what you are doing.

```
TextColor = Colors.Transparent;
Text = "Clear";
new Animation(v => WidthRequest = v, width, 70).Commit(this, "Animate", 16, 200, Easing.SinOut, finished: (v, c) =>
{
    FontFamily = _fontFamily;
    TextColor = Colors.Black;
    FontSize = 14;
    CornerRadius = 18;
    _canExecutCommand = true;
});
```

[image]

If you want to see more about animation, you can find the complete code in my [repo](https://github.com/PeterWessberg/MAUISamples).